# PHP Checking if a file exists in a directory

Tags: php

I'm creating a file uploader, and it checks to see if a file exists or not in a directory. If it does exist, I must come up with a new name for the file (I.E file.txt -> file1.txt). Not sure why, but it keeps on generating errors. Here's my code. Hopefully it isn't something painfully obvious.

```
$directory = "files/";
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$valid_name = true;
$counter = 0;
if(file_exists($directory . $_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
    $valid_name = false;
}
while(!$valid_name){
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'] . $counter;
    if(file_exists($directory . $name)){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific errors does your code generate?

Comment: What errors are the specific errors that it is generating?

Comment: U have an infinite loop. U should reassign valid_name after the file exists check

Comment: Always indent your code properly,t he problem is clearly visible now.

Comment: An the error is simply that the page will not load. No error printout, just nothing shows up.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to enable error reporting while testing, you can add error_reporting( E_ALL ); to the top of your file to enable it. A blank screen usually means there is an error but it isn't being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. This is much simpler and easier to understand.

```
$directory = "files/";
$counter = 0;
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
while(file_exists($directory . $name)){
    $counter++;
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'] . $counter;
}
```

Also your code does not generate `file.txt -> file1.txt` but `file.txt -> file.txt1` so does this one. To generate it properly play with the extension and the name.

Comment: `counter++;` is incorrect. It should be `$counter++;`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to name your variable correctly when using it:

```
$counter++;
// not counter++ but $counter++;
```

Comment: There it is. Thanks so much!

Comment: you are very much welcome mattegener. I hope to be of assistance anytime

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to change the value of `$valid_name`. Anyway, a simpler way to do that is just:

```
$directory = "files/";
$counter = "";
while (file_exists($directory . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . $counter)) {
    $counter++;
}
// Here the name is: $directory . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . $counter
```

Consider that after the first time `$counter++` is executed, it becomes "1", and then 2, etc...

---

A smaller code, just for fun:

```
$c = "";
while (file_exists("files/".$_FILES['filename']['name'].$c)) $c++;
// Here the name is: "files/".$_FILES['filename']['name'].$c
```

Comment: syntax error on counter

Answer (score 0):

The code has a number of problems, which I'll list followed by a cleanup.

1. Syntax error: counter is not prefixed with a $ sign
2. Styling: your code isn't formatted nicely and consequently you'll have a harder time identifying problems.
3. Logical flow: You're only checking for the existence of a single filename, not others.
4. You're not handling file extensions.

Try something like this:

```
    $directory = "files/";
    $path = pathinfo( $directory . $_FILES['filename']['name'] );
    $name = $path['filename'];
    $counter = 0;

    while ( file_exists( $path['dirname'] . $path['basename'] ) ) {
             $counter++;
             $path['filename'] = $name . $counter;
    }

    $outputFile = $path['dirname'] . $path['filename'] . '.' . $path['extension'];
```

Comment: I didn't include it earlier, but it rejects anything but a plain/text file.

Comment: In that case, you can just replace $path['extension'] with 'txt'